# Javascript: trigger multiple functions with one function. And displaying multiple images

Tags: javascript, image, function, var

I'm trying to make some sort of random images generator. I want to do this with the help of javascript, with multiple variables and functions.

This is how it stands right now:

**HTML**

```
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="StyleSheet.css">
<script src="functions.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Pack opener</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        test
    </div>

    <div class="buttons">
        <button class="button button1" onclick="genPack();">Generations</button>
    </div>

    <div class="imgholder">
        <img src="" alt="" id="img">
    </div>
</body>
```

**Javascript**

```
var img1 = new Array("image1.png", "image2.png");
var img2 = new Array("image3.png", "image4.png");
var img3 = new Array("image5.png", "image6.png");

function addimg1() {
var randomimg1= Math.floor(Math.random() * img1.length);
document.getElementById("img").src = img1[randomimg1];
}

function addimg2() {
    var randomimg2= Math.floor(Math.random() * img2.length);
    document.getElementById("img").src = img2[randomimg2];
}

function addimg3() {
    var randomimg3= Math.floor(Math.random() * img3.length);
    document.getElementById("img").src = img3[randomimg3];
}

function total() {
    addimg1();
    addimg1();
    addimg1();
    addimg1();
    addimg2();
    addimg2();
    addimg2();
    addimg3();
    addimg3();
    addimg3();
}
```

Currently the code is working fine, but it only shows the last function in the total function. I want it to display 10 images next to eachother.

Comment: document.getElementById("img") you are adding all images to single img tag so last call to addimg function value displays. try creating more img tags on your page or crate them using JS

Comment: okay, that makes a lot of sense. i will try that thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use do-while loop for this case:

```
function total(count1, count2, count3) {
  while (count1 > 0) {
    addimg1();
    count1 -= 1;
  }
  while (count2 > 0) {
    addimg3();
    count1 -= 1;
  }
  while (count3 > 0) {
    addimg3();
    count1 -= 1;
  }
}
```

So it will be one function, with given parameters - numbers of each function repeating count.

But it's still continue to be a bad code, I suggest you to rethink and rewrite your script.

Answer (score 0):

If you are to show all your images in one place then combine your arrays and then show one by one. This is a sample:

```
var img1 = new Array("image1.png", "image2.png");
var img2 = new Array("image3.png", "image4.png");
var img3 = new Array("image5.png", "image6.png");
function showImgs(){
    var allImg = img1.concat(img2).concat(img3);
    var img = document.getElementById('img');
    var cnt = 0, len = allImg.length;
    setInterval(function(){img.src = allImg[(cnt++) % len];}, 5000);
}

<button onclick="showImgs()">Show</button>
```